# Почему не сравнивает 2 строки?

Tags: python, строки, сравнение

У меня есть массив кортежей, и те же кортежи записаны в файл, я пытаюсь их сравнить как обычные строки (пытался и в разных форматах данных сравнить тоже не дало результатов)

Кортежи в файле выглядит так

```
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png')
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '2.png')
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png')
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '2.png')
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '2.png', '1.png')
```

Код по сравнению ниже:

```
ff = [('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png'),
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '2.png'),
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png'),
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '2.png'),
('1.jpg', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '6.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '1.png', '2.png', '1.png')
]

for i in ff:
    print("i = " + str(i))
    with open("log/logFile.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            print("line = " + str(line))
            if str(line) == str(i):
                print("Есть совпадение")
                print(str(i) + "\n ---> \n" + str(line))
```

При выводе явно видно что строки одинаковые, но условия не проходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конце каждой строки в файле есть символ перевода строки `\n`, просто уберите его и совпадения начнут находиться, я проверил:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
```

`strip()` убирает вообще все лишние пробельные символы и в начале и в конце строки, в вашем случае достаточно было бы просто убрать последний символ `line = line[:-1]` (я проверял, так тоже работает), но `strip()` всё-таки более универсальный метод, обычно в питоне используют именно его, когда есть предположение о наличии лишних пробельных символов по краям строки.